# Webpack + restAPI + Passport + authenticate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to make a bootstrap calendar work with a passport authentication. I got the bootstrap calendar from: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar.

I set up a passport authentication at port 8000 (which works) and the calendar is running with webpack on port 7000 (also works).

In general: I want to be able to log in to the calendar using passport. In detail: I want to get a authentication response from port 8000 when I am at port 7000. I want to call req.isAuthenticated. However, I can not make this work.

Before I start posting any code, does anyone have an idea or suggestions how to make this work? How webpack and my rest API can work together?

Thanks,

Bram